# Copying one or more layers (with properties, style, and path of source data) on ArcMap and paste into different ArcMap project?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, arcgis-10.2, layers, copy

I am using ArcMap 10.2.1 and i would like to take all the layers from one plan and bring them into another plan with all of the associated properties.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The best way to save all of the settings of a layer (or multiple layers) in a map document, is to create a layer package.

1. Select all of the layers you would like to save in the package
2. Right-click one of the selected layers and click Create Layer Package
3. Follow the Layer Package wizard, making sure to fill in all of the entries (such as summary and tags).
4. Once saved, you can then add the layer package in another map, and all of your packaged layers will appear as they did in the original map, referencing the original data.

For more information, see this [link](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//00660000045p000000).

The Layer package solution is good for some cases, but in most cases, using a Layer File (.lyr), can also be used to easily save the settings and properties of a layer(s) in a map document for use in a different map document.  The main difference between the two, is that packages can also store the data to be shared, whereas Layer Files cannot store, but only reference data.

To create a layer file:

1. Select all of the layers you like to include in the file
2. Right-click one of the selected layers and click Save as Layer File

For more information, see this [link](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#/Saving_layers_and_layer_packages/00s500000013000000/).

Comment: Thanks Evv, can you provide me with clarification of what the "Include Enterprise Geodatabase data instead of referencing the data" statement means?

Comment: @Matt - Checking "Include Enterprise Geodatabase data instead of referencing the data" will copy the SDE data you've selected into a packages directory.  If you do not check it, then the reference to the data in the SDE will be preserved.

Answer (score 2):

Depending on your precise requirements, I think layer files, rather than layer packages, may provide you with a better solution.

If you right-click on any layer (or layer group) in the Table of Contents and Save as Layer File you have all the Properties of that layer (but NOT its data) stored in a small file that can be easily added to another map.

If you need the data to be stored (duplicated) in the file that you are moving between maps then I would agree that layer packages should be used.

However, my recommendation would be to try [Layer Files](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//00s500000013000000) first:

> A layer can exist outside your map as a layer file (.lyr). This makes
>   it easy for others to access the layers you've built.
>
> You can share layers over the network and by e-mail.
>
> When users add a layer file to their maps, it will draw exactly as it
>   was saved as long as they can get access to the data referenced by the
>   layer. A common way that users help support this is to use relative
>   paths to each layer's data source.

In fact, if you have two instances of ArcMap open then there is no reason why you cannot multiple select layers from the Table of Contents in one, right-click to Copy them, and then go to the other ArcMap instance and right-click on a data frame name to Paste Layer(s).

Comment: Yeah, I don't see why a layer package would be necessary here

Comment: I did contemplate if layer files would be better as well.  I chose to go with the layer package, primarily because of the OP's request for the layer "properties".  Labeling for instance doesn't come over with a layer file.  Perhaps a better answer would be one explaining both layer packages and layer files?

Comment: @evv_gis What makes you think that label settings don't get saved into a layer file?

Comment: @PolyGeo - I could have sworn I ran into an issue where .lyr files did not support labeling.  But alas, as I test locally, everything appears to work just fine.

Answer (score 1):

I use a very simple method for this:

- Open the source MXD (containing the layer to be copied).
- Open the target MXD (where the layer should be copied to).
- Drag and drop the layer from the Table of Contents in the source MXD to the Table of Contents in the target MXD.

All of the properties of the layer (properties, style, labeling, path of source data, etc.) will be preserved.  No need to create layer packages or layer files.

Comment: I upvoted because this would work and is simple but I would recommend to only ever have one ArcMap session open at a time because of schema locks when editing, or when the same map gets opened in both and saving complications can arise.

Comment: @PolyGeo Thanks for the upvote.  I haven't had any problems using this method as long as I'm not in Editing Mode in either of the map documents.